# How do we add values in a Dependency Injection controller?

Tags: java, php, spring, laravel, dependency-injection

I have a data access object (DAO) class and need to inject it in a few models.

```
$dao = new DAO("mysql", "username", "password")
$userModel = new UserModel($dao);
```

Using dependency injection is very important to me. So it should look something like this:

```
//My DAO class
class DAO($connection, $username, $password) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
}

//My user model that I am injection the DAO class into
class UserModel(DAO $dao) {     //Where should i add my connection/username and password?
    $this->dao = $dao;
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to specify my connection and credentials in the constructor. I would also like to use the same instance of the DAO and UserModel elsewhere.

**Question**: How can I specific different connections/credentials to different models/services **and** keep the same DAO instance?

P.S. I've looked at pimple, laravel DI, Spring... but cannot seem to find a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's IoC container lets you specify different resolvers for different classes.

Use the `when()->needs()->give()` flow:

```
$container->when('UserModel')->needs('DAO')->give(function () {
    return new DAO('connectionA', 'usernameA', 'passwrodA');
});

$container->when('PostModel')->needs('DAO')->give(function () {
    return new DAO('connectionB', 'usernameB', 'passwrodB');
});
```

See [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container#binding). Look for the section titled **Contextual Binding**.